# adding a markers and updating the marker when lat and long change

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, marker

This portion of the code uses firebase it retrieves a uniquie id from the database and also its lat and long. if the uuid is myuuid it exits out of the function. but if not it goes into the next function addpoint.

```
    myFirebaseRef.on('child_changed', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
          // code to handle child data changes.

          var uuid = childSnapshot.key();
          var data = childSnapshot.val();
          var username = (data.username);
          var lat = (data.coords.latitude);
          var lon = (data.coords.longitude);
          if (uuid === myUuid) return



          addPoint(uuid, username, data);
        });
```

My function add point grabs uuid and latitude and longitude and plots it on the google maps the only problem that I have it doesn't move the marker it just keeps adds a marker.

```
    //add point
    function addPoint(uuid, username, data)
    {
    //  alert(username + data.coords.latitude + data.coords.longitude);
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        });
      marker.setMap(map);
    }
```

I would like to be able to plot markers on the map and give a marker a unique id so that if that marker changes positions just that marker moves. What is the best way about going about solving this problem. I am using google maps and firebase.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to keep your markers in an array, iterate through that array looking for an existing marker with that uuid, if it exists, move it, otherwise, create a new marker.

```
var gmarkers = [];
//add point
function addPoint(uuid, username, data)
{
  var i;
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude);
  // check for already existing marker
  for (i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers[i].uuid == uuid) { // existing marker, move it
       gmarkers[i].setPosition(position);
       return;
    }
  }
  // no existing marker, create a new one
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
  gmarkers.push(marker);
}
```